# Proper use of app.set() in express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I was having trouble accessing variables inside of my express middleware until I came across app.set() and app.get().  However, I was wondering if this is an appropriate use of app.set() and if there is perhaps a better way to access variables inside of middleware.  Here is an example:

```
var express = require("express");
var http = require("http");
var https = require("https");
var s3Client = require("./lib/s3_wrapper");
var drillClient = require('./lib/drill_wrapper');
var fs = require("fs");

var app = express();
app.set("s3Client", s3Client);
app.set("drillClient", drillClient);

var adminParams = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./conf/config.json"), "utf-8");
var adminBucket = adminParams.bucket;
var adminS3Client = new s3Client(adminParams);

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var accessKey = req.header("Authorization");
    adminS3Client.getObject({Bucket: adminBucket, Key: accessKey})
                 .then(function(results) {
                     req.config = JSON.parse(results.Body);
                     next();
                 })
                 .catch(function(err) {
                     console.log(err);
                     res.status(err.status).send(err.message);
                 });
});

app.get("/getObject/:bucket/:objectKey", function(req, res) {
    var params = {
        Bucket: req.params.bucket,
        Key: req.params.objectKey
    };
    var s3 = req.app.get("s3Client");
    var s3Client = new s3(req.config);
    s3Client.getObject(params)
            .then(function(results) {
                res.status(200).send(results.Body);
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                res.status(500).send(err.message);
            });
});
```

As you can see in the app.get("/getObject") route, I am using req.app.get("s3Client") because without that I was unable to create a new instance of my s3Client, since s3Client was always undefined at this point.  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I will risk and say that's not a good use. You are putting a whole module inside that variable? Why? If you need to use that module somewhere else, you simply require it again. If you have everything in one file, adding it on top once will suffice.

```
const s3Client = require("./lib/s3_wrapper");

app.get("/getObject/:bucket/:objectKey", function(req, res) {
  //s3Client was already defined.
  s3Client.something()
});
```

Then in some other file, somewhere.

```
//you import it again
const s3Client = require("./lib/s3_wrapper");

s3Client.something()
```

Comment: The problem though was that s3Client was always undefined in my app.get middleware even though it was required at the top of the file.

Comment: But the middleware was inside another file? if thats the case, you need to require s3Client in that file.

Comment: Unfortunately no, the require statement and the middleware are all in the same file.  That's what has me so confused.

Comment: Well, but aren't you overwriting that variable? require the s3Client using `const` so that it throws an error if you try to overwrite